# Regex trigger a match only when there are no paths after a particular url

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regex that matches URLS for content grouping in Google Tag Manager. The urls looks like the below:

A) `https://www.example.com/letter/abc`

B) `https://www.example.com/letter/abc/variations-of-abc`

For URL B, I use `.*\/letter\/.*\/.+` but for A, I can't figure it out. The one I have as of the moment is `.*\/letter\/.*$` but this matches both the urls unfortunately.

Any tips?

Comment: `.+\/letter\/[^\/]+$` to match first one

Comment: I won't develop for Google. Given that I'm using your examples  A & B trying to figure out  what you're trying to do with _`Google Tag Manager`_ and content management. I thought this was a regex question. It doesn't look like it.